# Problem related to output in python programming (not gives expected result)

Tags: python

I'm very beginner at python. Given code gives error with output. Want to correct it.

The mathematics behind the code is :

Let denote $S_m(n)=1^m+2^m+...+n^m$  and denote $D_x(y)$ is sum of digits of $y$ in base $x$.

*Example* $S_2(3)=14$ and $14=(1,1,1,0)_2$ then $D_2(14)=3$

*Theorem* if $x-1\mid y$ then $x-1\mid D_x(y)$

In code, for $n$, output shows "divisible" if $n-1\mid S_m(n-1)$ and shows "oooooooooook" if $n-1\mid D_n(S_m(n-1))$

**Problem** codes output must show "oooooooooook" if "divisible" had shown but greater value $m$ with greater $n$ does not shows expected result. How to correct it?

```
n= 2
m = 15
while n < 100:
    print("\n n=",n)

    num=n
    sum_num = 0
    for i in range(1, num): 
        sum_num += i**(m)
    n2 = (sum_num)


    if(n2%(num-1)== 0):
        print("diviasible")
    #else:
        #print("not divisible")

    rem_array = []
    while n2 != 0:
        mod = n2%n
        if mod != 0:
          rem = mod
          n2 = n2 - rem
          rem_array.append(round(rem))
          n2 = n2/n
        else:
            n2 = n2/n
            rem_array.append(0)

    #print(rem_array[::-1],sum(rem_array))

    if(sum(rem_array)%(n-1)==0):
        print("oooooooooook")
    #else:
        #print("not ok")



    n += 1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see all the points that are not ok, but using `//` integer division instead of `/` float division somewhat helps (tested, that worked).
Let me re-write the entire program:

```
s=lambda m,n:sum(i**m for i in range(1,n+1))
def digits(x,y):
    res=[]
    while y:
        res.append(y%x)
        y//=x
    return res
m=15
#theorem:
for n in range(2,101):
    s_m=s(m,n-1)
    assert s_m%(n-1) !=0 or sum(digits(n,s_m))%(n-1) == 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your return program. Did you find an error in my program?

Comment: Yes I did. After correction all the `/` into `//` it works just fine. Suppressed unneeded output version you can [try online](https://tio.run/##dVJbboMwEPznFFtQJTuFBqgqVag@SRpFVDGNVViQIa1yerosDg@l8QfCs7Ozj3Fz6U41vrw1tu9RQepVoCB59X5PptSA8A5JHGce0Akaa7AT/gcCKj9E6TGM50oh/7Xn6kA3Eoj5XtQWDBgEm@OXFkk4cGUGHFwmPCkwm42o5CiYkoJwMSrCoCnE0fxkCtNHQXCUSEVlZDZpXbsjlslb81lqX07BJm/bcQZdtvo2CesOhsRrHhOsrg65tfmF2tntGXJbSeGBis8yVX0kDrWGE2QKRtc81iQmRRYYz0ufaIiuuWP957xpNB4FAfI2b7udq66nu0P6Vzt2Q7uNTPFdlkXJPiQ3Zkw6Li1V2w7c8oDcXtPIKfZpfA0BWXgn7mwM2KrRkXo@387IhXdL5lCeOe6l4PCcEq/v/wA)

Comment: It has no output in either case, but if something goes wrong, the theoren prerequisite `div` would be true, `not div` would be false and the interpreter will have to check the second expression in `assert not div or sum(rem_array)%(n-1)==0` -- and raise `AssertionError` if it is `False`, you can try it, there will be in 'debug' window of tio.run if you convert all the `//` back into `/` and `rem_array.append(rem)` back to `rem_array.append(round(rem))`. What was the programming language you learned before python? Pascal, I guess? Not many languages use `round` so wide as Pascal does. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full solution, but your sum computation is very un-pythonic. You should use list comprehension instead:

```
num=15
m=5
s = [i*m for i in range(1,num)]
total_sum = sum(s)
```

Or, use lambda function + map:

```
f = lambda x:x*s
s= map(f, range(1,10))
total_sum=sum(s)
```